# Regex to Filtre google sheet column

Tags: regex, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to filter and extract the last any two character of a cell value from entire column.

I have tried the mentioned below:-

`=FILTER(Data!H:H,REGEXEXTRACT(Data!H:H, "\(..\)$"))`

But this is giving me error

I have values like this

```
Column H                 My Desired result
-----------          -----------------------
as/lk                        lk
dsfs                         fs
as*(&                        (&
asdda                        da
dasda                        da
```

Comment: Isn't `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(RIGHT(Data!H2:H, 2)))` all that you need?

Answer (score 0):

This was achieved by Array Formula:

`ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(Data!H2:H, "(..)$")))`